# SharePoint 2010 SP2 compability SQL Server 2012 SP4

Tags: 2010, sql-server-2012

Last year SQL Server 2012 got new service pack - SP4.
Is it compatible with SharePoint Server 2010 SP2 (build 14.0.7190.5000)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 supports SQL Server 2012 since ServicePack 1. See [System Requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.14).aspx#section4).

Any following ServicePacks or Cumulative Updates for SQL-Server 2012 are supported. You just cannot upgrade to SQL Server 2014 or later!

Comment: Thank you @MHeld - I know minimal requirement about SQL Server 2012 SP1. In this case, I am just curious about new SP4.

Comment: Thats no problem at all :)